# Sending email from secondary non-Gmail email in Gmail?

Tags: email, smtp, gmail, imap

I cannot set up a secondary Gmail address as a sender email in my primary Gmail address.

I want to be able to send emails from my primary Gmail account abc@gmail.com but with my secondary email def@owndomain.com.

The email server of my secondary domain def@owndomain.com is hosted by Google as part of my Google Workspace subscription. The domain is hosted on GoDaddy.

In the Gmail settings of my primary email abc@gmail.com, I try to add my secondary email here:
[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnrJ2.png)

However, when I proceed to enter my credentials in the next window, this shows:
[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdHxR.png)

POP and IMAP are both enabled.

What am I doing wrong? What do I need to do to set it up correctly?

Answer (score 1):

If IMAP is enabled on both accounts, that's good. Since you are using Google Workspace for your def@owndomain.com email, here are the things that you may do to it in order to address this concern:

1. Turn on the option "Allow users to send mail through an external SMTP server when configuring a "from" address hosted outside your email domain" from your Admin console.
2. Enable less secure apps (if 2-SV is turned off) or apps passwords (if 2-SV is on) in your Google Workspace account.

To turn on the option "Allow users to send mail through an external SMTP server when configuring a "from" address hosted outside your email domain" from your Admin console, you may go to "Apps" > "Google Workspace" > "Gmail" > "End user access" > "Allow per-user outbound gateways." Try again and see if that resolves your issue. Make sure that your username and password are correct.

If it doesn't, turn on less secure apps by going to this link: [Less Secure Apps](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps). Note: If the link doesn't work, you'll need to turn on less secure apps on your Admin console first by going to "Security" > "Access and data control" > "Less secure apps" > Choose the option "Allow users to manage their access to less secure apps" and then hit "Save."

Assuming that you have 2-Step Verification enabled, you may turn the option on by clicking on this link: [App Password](https://myaccount.google.com/apppasswords). Generate a mail app password for your device and use that as your password in the second screenshot you sent.

If these steps do not work, try again after 24 hours before contacting their support. The reason is because the changes you made on the console would need time to reflect in their system, as explained in this article. [How changes propagate to Google services](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7514107)

Reference:
[Allow per-user outbound gateways](https://support.google.com/a/answer/176054)

[Control access to less secure apps](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6260879)

[Sign in with app passwords](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833)